# JMeter HTTPS recording proxy issues from corporate proxy

Tags: https, proxy, jmeter, recorder

I am using **JMeter 3.0** version to record HTTPS Web UI. Our corporate uses configfile.proxy.com file for proxy settings in autoconfig options which doesn't have any port specified.
I am trying to invoke JMeter using these options, but without port it will not open, throwing error that port needs to be specified any suggestions?

```
jmeter -H configfile.proxy.com -P -u someusername -a someuserpassword -N localhost
```

Also, replaced configfile.proxy.com with ip address(it routes thru LB), didn't work.

Comment: Additional details: URL we are testing is local, so no proxy is required, however I cannot use localhost:XXXX in IE connection settings, as it will not work. Can we force JMeter to use no proxy settings? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

[Proxy Auto Config (PAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) files are slightly different beasts, you cannot use them with `-H` command line argument.

You can determine real proxy host and port using i.e. [pacparser](https://github.com/pacparser/pacparser) library.

Alternative option is recording your test scenario using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), Chrome automatically picks up system-wide proxy settings hence you won't have to worry about it (at least during recording).

If JMeter will need to go through proxy to reach the application under test - you will still need to go the "pacparser" way.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitri! Looked up Chrome Extension, as per our corporate policy, we can't upload any scripts/material to external websites.

Comment: Additional details: URL we are testing is local, so no proxy is required, however I cannot use localhost:XXXX in IE connection settings, as it will not work. Can we force JMeter to use no proxy settings? Any suggestions please